# Configuring Team City internal.properties to increase git fetch memory

Tags: github, teamcity

When pulling from GIT my Team City install is getting an out of memory error.

According to the Team City documentation I should be able to increase the memory assigned to the git fetch process, by setting the value for teamcity.git.fetch.process.max.memory to something greater than the default 512MB.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Git+%28JetBrains%29#Git%28JetBrains%29-InternalProperties

Problem is there does not appear to be an internal.properties file in the location specified.

I have tried creating one in the TeamCity/conf/internal.properties as suggested here:

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/302596

But I still get the out of memory issue when Team City tries to pull from github

thx

Comment: How much memory did you give it? It should be no less than the biggest object in your repository. Also please check if the setting has an effect: when TeamCity runs fetch you should see a separate java process in the process explorer and you can check that it uses right amount of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was to set a global system variable on the server to pass a value into the team city service when it starts up.

So for example:

variable name: TEAMCITY_SERVER_OPTS
variable value: Dteamcity.git.fetch.process.max.memory=1024M

This is specific to Team City 7.1 and does not work with the previous releases.

Comment: Is there a setting in TC for this? i.e. avoiding an OS env variable?